# How to run and restore Eclipse which in remote machine [linux] from a local machine [windows 7]

Tags: linux, eclipse, screen, tmux, x11-forwarding

My situation is :

1) I have a remote server , Ubuntu LTS 14.04

2) It has Eclipse in it (of course with huge workspace)

3) I am using Windows 7 as my local Machine

4) I want to run Eclipse from "Windows" on "Linux" and use it for developing. [I can, how ? mentioned below]

5) When I exit eclipse it should keep running on server [Linux]

6) I can come back and open the same session of eclipse.

What I have done so far ?

1) Installed Xming

2) Installed Putty and enabled X11 forwarding.

3) Connect to remote

4) Open ./eclipse.sh

Works fine

But if I close, it will destroy the session

I also tried the following :

Method 1 :

1) Installed tmux on Linux

2) Created new session

3) BUT when I try to run eclipse in this session, Error says It cannot open Display

Method 2 :

1) Installed xpra on Linux

2) created a display

3) BUT when I try to open eclipse in THIS session , again the same error.

So ,

Can some one please help me telling the step by step process to run Eclipse on Remote so that It keeps on running and I can use THE SAME ECLIPSE in my windows as and when required WITHOUT closing the eclipse in the remote machine?

I dont want to use remote project/system explore feature of eclipse.

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).

Install VNC server on your Ubuntu. It might already be there as this is a common deamon on Linux. Start the session

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1600x1200
```

stating your preferred resolution of the desktop.

Install VNC client on Windows machine. Start it and enter the adress of your Ubuntu:  ip.address:display. For instance

```
192.168.1.1:1
```

(:0 is display you used in vncserver call above). If everything works fine you should see XWindows on your Ubuntu. Start Eclipse there and you are all set. It will run there and survive disconnection of your VNC client until you kill the vncserver session with a command like:

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

Comment: Grzejszczak : 
Thanks for your answer, but I dont want to use VNC . My friend feed backed me that it is very slow even in LAN . Do you have any other solution

Comment: Tight VNC can be pretty good even on poor remote connections. I suggest you try it out and see, if the performance is good enough. I can't think of anything that could be more suitable to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the `DISPLAY` variable of your Ubuntu machine to your Windows machine and then run it from the Ubuntu machine. Let's say, IP address of your Windows machine is `1.2.3.4` then you can set the DISPLAY variable to `1.2.3.4:0`.

From windows machine, SSH to Ubuntu machine and set `DISPLAY` variable

```
export DISPLAY=1.2.3.4:0
```

Then run eclipse from Ubuntu and it should show up on your Windows machine. You can also access your remote code (i.e. the code from Ubuntu machine) and modify and save it to the remote machine. Hope it helps!